# Gnome 3 Top bar "application Icon Missing" - Cent OS 7

Tags: centos, gnome

I just want to know how to enable icon of the program that is opened in the top bar.

Maybe its a lame question. Its just for aesthetics.

For reference consider the image

[image]

Here logo of setting should appear, which dynamically changes to the application opened. But in my case it doesn't. Pls help me to enable it

Thank You

Few Information

OS : CentOS 7 
Desktop Environment : Gnome 3

Comment: It's most probably due to the shell theme you're using. Change it to something else (e.g. default shell theme) and the icons should appear.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that but it isn’t working